# Can i use HTTP POST method with jquery datatables sAjaxSource and webapi

Tags: jquery, datatables, asp.net-web-api

By default datatables will get data with HTTP GET method. From research i got to know we can configure datatable to use HTTP POST method. like following

http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

But my problem is in my code we have used(by former developer)

```
   $("#example").dataTable({
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": 'api/GetEmpAll/',
                    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "aoColumns": [
                            { "mData": "FirstName","sWidth": "100px" },
                            { "mData": "LastName" },
                    ]
                });
```

and with this when i try to give "type": "POST" it is not at all calling my web api POST method. 
when i give "type": "POST" , my web api's breakpoints will never be hit at all.

**can someone please tell me how to tell datatables to use POST method "sAjaxSource" and web api.**

Comment: so i am using older version of datatables ?

Comment: yes.  An easy way to tell is that in the new version the author got rid of all the letter prefixes.  So like aoColumns is now just columns, bServerSide is just serverSide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also using dataTable and I've noticed they actually have two versions of the API. Your code uses "bServerSide" while the example you've posted uses "serverSide".

Please check if you're using the right version. I am not sure both are backward compatible (or even worse, if the documentations suits the library you're using)

Try using

```
"sServerMethod": "POST"
```

instead. See the legacy documentation at http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: ok i got that and tried the same but the result is same my web api break point is not hitting at all ... +1 for let me know that i m using datatables old version

Comment: don't forget to hard refresh your browser to force it to load the new javascript

Comment: thx man ..  i never knew that we are using legacy datables .. and this did work for me ... so accepted and +1